# Unable to connect azure vm other than port 80

Tags: azure

I have changed port 80 to 8081 for IIS default website on Azure Windows 2019 server and also opened all ports, all sources and all destinations in azure portal inbound networks but still cannot access the site using port 8081

I have been debugging for elasticsearch port 9200 connection issue then found out same issue with others as well like 8081.

Comment: Do you have an application hosted on that VM that's setup in cloudflare?

Comment: application hosted on azure Win 2019 server and trying to access from my laptop.